# Meteor: How execute JS after insert in collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am working on a chat app using Meteor.
After sending the message, it should show the message and scroll to the bottom. But how can I execute a JS to scroll down, AFTER the insert?

```
 Template.addMessage.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
       Messages.insert({
            user: 'username',
            message: 'my message',
            date: new Date()
        });
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
     }
 });
```

Apparently it is scrolling down before the view refreshes with the new record. How can it be executed after the view updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Collection.insert's callback](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-insert)

```
 Template.addMessage.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
       Messages.insert({
            user: 'username',
            message: 'my message',
            date: new Date()
        }, function(){
           // add your code here
           window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! And how can I do the same callback in the helper find? `return Messages.find({}, {sort: {date: 1}}).fetch();`

Comment: @ViníciusMichelutti find() works reactively. If you're trying to modify the dom manually, it generally means you're doing something "wrong" that you could be doing reactively. You can use Collection.observe() to react to changes in the query result set and apply some logic there. I would suggest you check out Discover Meteor if you haven't already ;)